# Error al registrarse en un formulario php, mysql, ajax

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, pdo

estoy intentado hacer un formulario de registro con php, mysql y ajax.

El error es que no me registra el usuario en la base de datos, doy todos los parametros con las variables correspondientes sin embargo no registra nada en la base de datos

Estoy usando PDO, sucede que al mandar el submit mediante el botón salta error y no entiendo por qué, gracias de antemano =D

También hago uso de google recaptcha, he borrado la clave secreta por motivos de seguridad.
Agradecería cualquier sugerencia para mejorar la seguridad del formulario!

Código de PHP:

```
require '../../config.php'; // datos de la base de datos, database data

function isNull($data){
    if (strlen(trim($data)) < 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function verifyPassword($pass1, $pass2) {
    if (strcmp($pass1, $pass2) !== 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function isEmail($email) {
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function registerUser($username, $email, $password, $btc_wallet, $user_type){
    global $con;
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (username, email, password, btc_wallet, user_type) VALUES(:username, :email, :password, :btc_wallet, :user_type)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':btc_wallet', $btc_wallet, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':user_type', $user_type, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        return $con->insert_id;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $giveBack = [];
    $user_type = 2;
    $secretKey = "google_secret_key";
    introducir el código aquí
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $btc_wallet = $_POST['wallet'];
    $email = strtolower($_POST['email']);
    $clave = $_POST['password'];
    $con_password = $_POST['con_password'];
    $captcha = $_POST['grecaptcha'];

    $search_user = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1");
    $search_user->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $search_user->execute();

    //if (!captcha) $giveBack[] = "Por favor, verifica el captcha";
    if (isNull($username) || isNull($btc_wallet) || isNull($email) || isNull($clave) || isNull($con_password)) $giveBack[] = "Por favor, completa todos los campos.";
    if (!isEmail($email)) $giveBack[] = "Email invalido";
    if (!verifyPassword($clave, $con_password)) $giveBack[] = "Las contraseñas no coinciden";
    if ($search_user->rowCount() == 1) {
        # Usuario ya existe, proceder a enviar un mensaje
        $giveBack['usernameError'] = "Este usuario ya existe";
        $giveBack['isLogin'] = false;
    }

    if (count($giveBack) == 0) {
        $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$captcha");
        $arr = json_decode($response, TRUE);

        if ($arr['success']) {
            # Creamos el hash para el password
            $password = password_hash($clave, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            $register = registerUser($username, $email, $password, $btc_wallet, $user_type);

            if ($register > 0) {
                # Recuperando el id
                $user_id = $con->lastInsertId();
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = (int) $user_id;
                $giveBack['redirect'] = '';
                $giveBack['isLogin'] = true;
            } else {
                $giveBack[] = 'Error al registrar';
            }
        } else {
            $giveBack['errorToCheckCaptcha'] = 'Error al comprobar el captcha';
        }
    }
    json_encode($giveBack);
} else {
    exit("Fuera de aquí");
}
```

Código de Javascript:

```
const url = 'http://localhost/faucet_st/api/user/signup/process-signup.php';

var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var wallet = document.getElementById("btc_wallet").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
var con_password = document.getElementById("con_password").value;

var data = {
    username: username,
    wallet: wallet,
    email: wallet,
    password: wallet,
    con_password: con_password,
    grecaptcha: grecaptcha.getResponse()
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
})
.done((res) => {
    console.log(res);
})
.fail((e) => {
    console.log(e);
})
.always(() => {});
});
```

Agradecería que me ayudaran con este problema, he intentado resolverlo todo el día, pero no encontré solución, seguiré buscando la solución, pero agradezco cualquier ayuda de parte suya.

Comment: Pero, ¿cuál es el error?¿Podrías agregarlo a la pregunta? Puedes pulsar en [edit] para ello. Gracias.

Comment: Esta consulta de suyo es incorrecta:  `SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1` porque estás usando consultas preparadas, debes escribirla así: **`SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username=:username LIMIT 1`** ... Sigo revisando...

Comment: Lo siento soy nuevo en esto, ya edite la pregunte, muchas gracias por ayudarme!

Comment: Prueba a ver si funciona así. Aunque veo errores lógicos en tu código. Por ejemplo, primero haces el `SELECT` del usuario, y luego preguntas si la variable que se usará como criterio en el `SELECT` está vacía o nula. Debería ser lo contrario ¿no? Primero verificar el estado de la variable y solamente cuando tenga datos mandar el `SELECT`.

Comment: Ya edite el código como me lo señalaste, pero no registra nada en la base de datos.
Te adjunto una captura de lo que obtengo en la consola, no deberia salir si se guarda la información en la base de datos:
https://i.imgur.com/QQhqw66.png

Comment: Tu captura de pantalla no ayuda a encontrar el problema. ¿Qué es lo que dices que no debería salir?

Comment: Al utilizar ajax, llama a la función fail(), pero creo que el error debe estar en el lado del servidor, de todos modos te adjunto una captura aquí: https://i.imgur.com/9pt34qi.png

Comment: A ver, es complicado revisar un código completo en una captura que por lo demás se ve truncada. Además, si vas a trabajar con PHP debes aprender un método eficiente de depurar errores. Si sale `fail`, como bien dices, es muy probable que haya un error en el servidor. Lo más óptimo es que revises el log de errores de PHP, te dirá exactamente cuál es el error y dónde se encuentra. Este tipo de códigos dan error por lo más mínimo, hasta por una comilla de más o de menos.